# jgestures fired twice

Tags: jquery, touch, jgestures

I´m using jgestures for my lightbox which i have in my wordpress theme

on touch devices i want to navigate to the next or previous image with swipe gestures

when i use swipeleftdown as event, the function is called twice, 
when i use 3 events, like in my example, the function gets called six times

i want the function to get called only one time

```
jQuery('#lightboxcontainer').bind('swipeleftdown swipeleftup swipeleft', function(){
    if(jQuery(".arrowNext").attr("href")){
        showNextImage();
    }
});
```

Comment: It could be possible that if sees the swipleft and swipeleftdown as two events.

Comment: when i use only one event the functions is called twice, so for every event i bind the function gets called 2 times

Comment: Thats what im saying could it be possible that the .arrow.next is true twice?

Comment: if its the first of five pictures for example, .arrowNext is true up to four times

Comment: whats the code behind showNextImage(); ?

Comment: i think for my case it is not relevant what code is behind the function. if i make an alert instead of the function call it gets fired twice also

Comment: well try to console.log(this) too see whats in it.

Comment: i can alert(this) because on the mobile devices i dont have firebug. i get [object HTMLDivElement] - six times